# How to flatten an array like this using Python?

Tags: python, arraylist, flatten

I have this array here:

```
a = np.array([[['1','2','3'],['10','11','12']],[['4','5','6'],['13','14','15']],[['7','8','9'],['16','17','18']]])
```

and I want to transform it like this:

```
>>>[['1' '2' '3'] ['4' '5' '6'] ['7' '8' '9'] ['13' '14' '15'] ['10' '11' 12'] ['16' '17' '18']]
```

i'm using Numpy's .flatten(), but it is not working

thanks

Comment: How did you use `numpy.flatten()`?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
a.transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Comment: `transpose(1, 0, 2)` means swap dimensions `1`, and `0` of the ndarray but keep `2` in place.